X11 forwarding on SDDM
I am trying to forward X11 from my PC (server) to my laptop (client). I allowed X11 forwarding in my sshd_config. Running ssh user@ip -X returns Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated and $DISPLAY is not set. Running ssh user@ip -Y as per this returns Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding. and $DISPLAY is set, however running any commands that normally spawn a GUI fails
[playerxyt@playerspc ~]$ dolphin
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display localhost:10.0
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, vkkhrdisplay, offscreen, vnc, wayland, linuxfb, wayland-egl, minimalegl, minimal, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)

Also -Y seems to be a security problem. I followed this but the command fails. My main issue is my DM. My laptop uses lightdm which puts my xauth file in ~/.Xauthority but my PC uses SDDM which puts it in /tmp/xauth_XXXX meaning that I can't make persistent changes to the Xauth file anyways.
Both the client and server run X, not wayland. The server has plasma while the client has i3wm, both run arch.
How can I fix this (even if it means switching DMs)

Have you tried to delete ~/.Xauthority on the machine you want to display and then ssh -XC  again?

@AdrianZaugg yes, like I said $XAUTHORITY points to /tmp/xauth_XXXX which get deleted when I reboot. I don't have a ~/.Xauthority

Sorry, I got confused from which machine you connect to which: With X11 the server is the machine the graphics are displayed and at the same time this is your ssh client. So I assume you connect by ssh from the Laptop to the PC and you would like to display a program running on the PC on your Laptop. The ssh server on the PC creates a Magic cookie when connecting. The ssh client should be able to add that cookie, so remote windows are allowed to display. I believe this step fails on your system. You could try to set XAUTHORITY="~/.Xauthority " in your ~/.bashrc on the PC and retry.
